# How to connect to a STOMP websocket with Flutter

Tags: flutter, stomp

I'm trying to connect to a stomp WebSocket with Flutter.
I'm using the stomp_dart_client 0.3.8 library.
Here is my code (I followed the documentation on their GIT):

```
void onConnectcallback(StompClient client, StompFrame connectFrame) {
  client.subscribe(
      destination: '/notification/app/test',
      headers: {' Auth-Token': Statics.accessToken},
      callback: (  StompFrame connectFrame )  {
        List<dynamic> result = json.decode(connectFrame.body);
        print(connectFrame.body);
        print(result);
        print('it worked');
      }
  );
  print("i think i work");
}


testconnection()  {
  final stompClient= StompClient(config: StompConfig(
    url:' ws://messagerie-rcc.be-idys.com',
    onWebSocketError: (dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
    onStompError:(dynamic error) => print(error.toString()),
    onConnect: onConnectcallback,
    stompConnectHeaders: {' Auth-Token': Statics.accessToken},
    webSocketConnectHeaders: {' Auth-Token':Statics.accessToken},));
  stompClient.activate();
  print('I think its workinf');
}
```

And then I call the testconnection().
when I debug it's skipping the:

```
onConnect: onConnectcallback,
```

I tried adding parameters and make it

```
onConnect: onConnectcallback(client, connectFrame),
```

I get:

```
The method 'subscribe' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: subscribe(callback: Closure: (StompFrame) => Null, destination: "/notification/app/test", headers: _LinkedHashMap len:1)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use plain authentication instead of Tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I decided to initialize my stomp in variables declaration, like this :

```
StompClient stompClient = StompClient(
  config: StompConfig(
    url: 'ws://yourhost',
    onConnect: onConnected,
    stompConnectHeaders: {'Authorization': '$token'},
    webSocketConnectHeaders: {'Authorization': '$token'},
    onWebSocketError: (e) => print(e.toString()),
    onStompError: (d) => print('error stomp'),
    onDisconnect: (f) => print('disconnected'),
  ),
);

So, then afterwards call the activate method.
```